# Real-time QR update using Firebase

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, zxing.net

I've been making a project in Xamarin.Forms that use Firebase (which for now only saves items) to make a list.
I then retrieve and convert that list to string using `IValueConverter`, and I finally use that same string to convert it to QR code using ZXing.

In my code `ItemViewPage.xaml`, I used a `CollectionView` to check whether the database is updating in the first place.

My problem is that the QR code doesn't show until I remove and retype my binding in `BarcodeValue` during hot reload.

**ItemViewPage.xaml:**

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:CollectionConverter x:Key="CollectionConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding DatabaseItems}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Product}" FontSize="Large"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

        <zxing:ZXingBarcodeImageView BarcodeValue="{Binding DatabaseItems, Converter={StaticResource CollectionConverter}}" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300">
            <zxing:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>
                <zxingcommon:EncodingOptions Width="300" Height="300"/>
            </zxing:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>
        </zxing:ZXingBarcodeImageView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**ItemViewPage.xaml.cs:**

```
namespace InventorySample.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ItemViewPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MyDatabaseRecord> DatabaseItems { get; set; } = new 
            ObservableCollection<MyDatabaseRecord>();


        readonly FirebaseClient firebaseClient = new FirebaseClient("https://inventorysample-eca49-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/");

        public ItemViewPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;

            var collection = firebaseClient
                .Child("Products")
                .AsObservable<MyDatabaseRecord>()
                .Subscribe((dbevent) =>
                {
                    if(dbevent.Object != null)
                    {
                        DatabaseItems.Add(dbevent.Object);
                    }
                }); 
        }
    }
}
```

**CollectionConverter.cs**

```
namespace InventorySample
{
    public class CollectionConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            ObservableCollection<MyDatabaseRecord> Items = (ObservableCollection<MyDatabaseRecord>)value;

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(item.Product);
            }
    
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I've already tried multiple things and am completely stumped. Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this only an issue during hot reload or also when you run it normally?

Comment: If by normally you mean having it installed on an android device, then it just won't show and with no way of retyping the binding, the qr code won't update. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Wrap DatabaseItems.Add in Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread:  `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => { DatabaseItems.Add(dbevent.Object); };` That will ensure xamarin sees the change on thread/at time when it can update based on it.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, I had to still retype the binding, what's weird is that the QR actually shows immediately without the the converter but when scanned shows this: System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection'1[InventorySample.Models.MyDatabaseRecord] So I'm thinking it has something to do with how the converter is called since the binding seems to react to updates quickly wdyt?